# Start a new Activity with an extra class (android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've found some examples, but it didn't help me out. I'm creating an app for my mobile phone but I ran into a problem. The problem is I want to start a new Activity in my new class but it doesn't work.

This class below is where I want to start the new activity called "PhoneStatus"

```
package com.example.phone;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Controller {
    Button ps;
    PhoneStatus c_ps;

    public Controller(Button ps) {
        this.ps = ps;
        c_ps = new PhoneStatus();
        createPhone_status();
    }

    private Boolean createPhone_status() {
        ps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent("com.example.phone.PhoneStatus");
                c_ps.startActivity(it);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can some one help me start a new Activity? Because this gave me an error and crashed the app.
The Activity1 (so the MainActivity) is working fine.

> The error:
>   *07-22 15:38:35.946: E/AndroidRuntime(30784): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference*

Comment: [check here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). also: probably duplicated

Comment: You have to pass First Activity Object to this class constructor from that activity obj you can call startActivity method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneStatus is an Activity. You should **never** be instantiating Android application components (like Activities) yourself. It the responsibility of the OS to do this, because the OS needs to do some extra setup like attaching a base Context to the Activity. Because you instantiated it yourself with `new PhoneStatus()`, this setup has not happened and the call to `startActivity()` results in an error occurring somewhere in the call stack. The earliest you should try to use an Activity is in its `onCreate()` callback.

I think the easiest solution for you is this:

```
ps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent it = new Intent("com.example.phone.PhoneStatus");
        ps.getContext().startActivity(it);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the proper way it to create and start the new Activity?

Comment: From an `Activity` or `Context` that was created for you, not one you created (because you should not be creating one). You need to provide a `Context` to your `Controller` class (or, as I did instead, take it from the `Button` that you already have).

Answer (score 1):

in general, use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I get an error with this code because i'm trying to start a new Activity from a class that does not extends from Activity.

Answer (score 1):

your 'Controller' is simple java class, so you will not found any context to start actvity. So you need to pass context as param in your 'Controller' constructor.

```
    public Controller(Button ps, Context context) {
            this.ps = ps;
            c_ps = new PhoneStatus();
            createPhone_status();
            this.context = context;
    }
```

store that context in that class and using that context start activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, newActivityName.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and If PhoneStatus is an Activity then @Karakuri is right, you can follow that suggestion

happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

LoginActivity -- current activity name
AboutActivity -- next Activity need to go   (Phonestatus)

Comment: I get an error with this code because i'm trying to start a new Activity from a class that does not extends from Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling an `Activity` outside an `Activity`, so you gonna need:

```
    Intent it = new Intent("com.example.phone.PhoneStatus");
    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //You should start a new task
    ps.getContext().startActivity(it);
```